# Is this integer overflow exploitable?

Tags: exploit, c, integer-overflow

```
char buffer[100];
char buffer_size[40];
int i;
fgets(buffer_size,32,stdin);
i = atoi(buffer_size);

if(i+1 < 100)
  if(i>=0)
    fgets(buffer,i,stdin);
```

Comment: OP, why would you delete your questions content? This might - by chance - be useful for others. And why are you sorry for asking? There is however a „thank you“ button for the person to answer your question best: it’s called „accept“ and is a green check mark.

Comment: Downvoted: please provide at least some form of context. Also this seems a lot like homework.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since `i` could be `INT_MAX` (0x7FFFFFFF), which is just over 2 billion, but if you add 1 to it you get 0x80000000 (just below negative two billion, for signed ints)... that passes the test and you end up trying to fill a 100 byte buffer with up to 2 gigs of data. That's bad (and exploitable), yes.